# Unable to define a global alias in zsh

Tags: zsh

I want to define a global alias that types a one-liner.

```
alias -g TLOGS3="\`find /var/log/trafficserver/ -name access.log\* -printf \"%T@ %Tc %p\n\" | sort -n | tail -n 3 | cut -d \" \" -f 9 | tr \"\n\" \" \"\`"
```

I want to type this:-

```
`find /var/log/trafficserver/ -name access.log\* -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 3 | cut -d " " -f 9 | tr "\n" " "`
```

But, for some reason when I type (TLOGS3 and spacebar) in terminal (zsh shell), I get this:-

```
➜ $?=0 /home/arastogi [10:37AM] % TLOGS3find: `/var/log/trafficserver/': No such file or directory
`find /var/log/trafficserver/ -name access.log\* -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 3 | cut -d " " -f 9 | tr "\n" " "`
```

Can someone help me regarding what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it would seem that the directory `/var/log/trafficserver/` does not exist or at least `find` is unable to access it.

And I would guess that the error message appears after typing <kbd>Space</kbd> because <kbd>Space</kbd> is bound to a widget, that automatically tries to expand aliases. If your alias usually get replaced by their full command, this is definitelly the case. Otherwise you can check this with

```
bindkey " "
```

If there is no widget bound to <kbd>Space</kbd> this should show

```
" " self-insert
```

It might also show

```
" " magic-space
```

This is an internal widget that expands history references (like `!!`) before also inserting a space. But it does not affect aliases.

If it shows anything else, this is most likely the widget that expands the alias. Of course the underlying issue is still, that the directory does not exist or is inaccessible.

---

Aside from that the alias seems to be fine and works for me, although I had to change `-f 9` into `-f 8`, as find only returns eight field for me, probably due to differing locale settings. But I would suggest using `zsh`'s glob qualifiers to achieve the same in a less complicated way:

```
alias -g TLOGS3='/var/log/trafficserver/**/access.log*(Om[-3, -1])'
```

This expands to a list of files in `/var/log/trafficserver` or any of its subdirectories (`**`), matching the name `access.log*`. This list is ordered descending (`O`) by modification time (`m`; latest modification first) and limited to the third last to last element (`[-3,-1]`).

If there are no subdirectories and the file order can be reversed, this can be shortened to

```
alias -g TLOGS3='/var/log/trafficserver/access.log*(om[1,3])'
```

`o` orders ascending, so the first through third elements are the three newest ones.